# Low Variables with Matrix and Assets

Tags: matrix, assets, low-variables, bug

We've setup LV with a Matrix field, inside of which is an Assets field. When we submit the changes, these are written to the DB but when the page reloads, the Asset field is blank.

It appears this problem has happened before but the fix from back then seems to have become inaffective: https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/assets_field_used_in_matrix_as_a_low_variable_doesnt_pull_information_from_db

Is anyone able to help with this one? Our setup is:

- EE 2.6.1
- LV 2.3.5
- Matrix 2.5.5
- Assets 2.1.3

Sam

Answer (score 2):

try setting the `is_draft` column in `exp_matrix_data` table to NOT NULL with the default of 0. This will be fixed in the next Matrix version.

Comment: Thanks Andris but that one didn't seem to work. We actually ran another test with just Low Variables and Assets (no Matrix) and the same problem occurred.

Comment: Sam, this seems like a good candidate for sending CP and FTP access our way to support@pixelandtonic.com, then :)