# File Field within Matrix inside a Low Variable fails to update file field on save

Tags: matrix, file-uploads, low-variables

I'm having a similar issue to [this one](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11318/low-variables-with-matrix-and-assets) but with a standard File field type instead of Assets. I tried just a File field type inside a Low Variable and it updated properly. This was dated bcd in June and it appears the problem was resolved with an update to Assets. Any ideas why this happens with the File field type? Solutions?

EE 2.7.2, Matrix 2.5.9, Low Variables 2.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to have been an issue with Matrix and P&T has pushed out a version that resolves this issue. In fact this is the only update according to their change log. Nice job P&T.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest reuploading the Matrix theme files. It's possible they were missed or corrupted  if you recently upgraded.